# chrome cookie size limit

Tags: cookies, google-chrome, limit

I'm writing into a session cookie from my plugin in chrome. The browser seems to have a strict limit of 4kb for cookie size. It doesnt seem the case in firefox. Is there anyway i can increase the cookie size limit in chrome?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to store so much in a cookie?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5381526/632951

Comment: @CResults, Because HTML5 localStorage is capped at 5 MB.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Chrome supports HTML5 localStorage that allows you to use a dictionary style look up.  You can use this to store larger amounts of data instead of passing them back and forth using cookies.

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted, the question is about cookies. HTML5 Web Storage is is great but vulnerable to XSS. So not as safe as httponly cookies https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage#conclusion

Answer (score 22):

According to RFC 1012 cookie size must not be limited by user agent. But the minimum capabilities of a browser or user agent should be at least 4096 bytes per cookie. This limit is applied to the name=value portion of the cookie only.

So some browsers can support longer cookies as well.
List :

1. Internet Explorer 8 allowed cookies up to 4095 bytes
2. Chrome 9
   allowed cookies up to 4096 bytes
3. Opera 11 allowed cookies up to 4096 bytes
4. Safari 5
   allowed coookies up to 4097 bytes
5. Firefox 3.6.3 allowed cookies up to 4097 bytes

**Source** of Answer : http://webdesign.about.com/od/cookies/f/web-cookies-size-limit.htm

Answer (score 12):

You can't change the cookie size but you can use several cookies and span your data across them, keeping one cookie as a pointer to other cookies so you know what they're called, how many there are, etc (like a partition table on a harddisk).

But perhaps you're approaching this the wrong way. If you need to do something like this, you're probably better off storing the data online as it has a better chance of survival and if you tie it in with some user registration, it's portable too.

There are other options like Mozilla Weave and Google Gears, but Gears was recently announced to be discontinued.

Comment: A nice reply, But he should rather stick to Local Storage as it is the standard and also becoming main stream for such tasks :)