# How can I pass string or array to another page without querystring in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have string variable and array in my page. I want to pass these variables to another pages. For string variable yes I can use querystring but for array what can I do?

Comment: you can use local storage (indexDB) if mordern browser. else go for cookies if data is not too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localStorage can only handle strings which is why you have to first convert your array into a string before storing it.

```
var yourArray = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

// Store it
localStorage['foo'] = JSON.stringify( yourArray );

// And retrieve it
var storedArray = JSON.parse( localStorage['foo'] );
```

Like others have said the above only works with modern browsers so if you are worried about browser compatibility you can store your array in a cookie.

If you have concerns regarding size restrictions of cookies and the size of your array check out this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381526/what-are-the-current-cookie-limits-in-modern-browsers)

Comment: I'm using this method now and also storing the cookie. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can store it in `localStorage` assuming the user has a modern browser. Otherwise you could serialize it, e.g. to JSON, and store it in a cookie.