# Share Json between html pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have used jQuery AJAX got a string of JSON  in the login page. How can I use it in other pages. Are there some method to store the JSON and access it anywhere in my website.
ps. I didn't use any other server script, it is only a html website. The JSON string is about 5K byte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("json", JSON.stringify(json));
// Retrieve
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("json"));
```

Comment: @bohan If it solved your problem, you have to upvote and accept this answer.

Comment: If you want just to share data between pages in the same browser session than `sessionStorage` is better choice than `localStorage` as it will not leave remnants.

Answer (score 1):

You  can use `localStorage` or `cookie` to store your `json`.

Read about **[Web-storages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)**

But remember `cookie` has size limitations, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381526/what-are-the-current-cookie-limits-in-modern-browsers).

Answer (score 0):

You can store json in `.json` files, and requests can go to those files and parse the responsetext with `JSON.parse`