# What is the maximum length of a HTTP cookie in different browsers?

Tags: http, cookies, browser

What is the maximum length of a HTTP cookie in different browsers? Does it differ between browsers?

Does the HTTP protocol dictate it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key

Comment: You might wanna check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381526/what-are-the-current-cookie-limits-in-modern-browsers