# sharing a JSON object among HTML files using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have an HTML page and a java script file. When I click on a button in my html page I get a Json string in the java script file from the server. The Json string contains data that I want to use in other Html pages, so what would be a good technique to share the json string or object among the html pages, using java script only???

thx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that counts as "JavaScript only", but you could use DOM Storage.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('theData', theData)
```

That way it even survives closing the window (which you may or may not want).

Comment: it workd fine on chrome but doesnt work on firefox, and i am afraid it wont work on mobile phones browsers

Answer (score 1):

PersistJS is a wrapper around the new storage features in modern browsers (LocalStorage,globalStorage,openDatabase, gears,...).  It uses feature detection to select the most appropriate storage solution. Including falling back to Cookies/Flash on older browsers.

http://pablotron.org/software/persist-js/

or more details on how it works at: http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557

Comment: I assume we are talking about WAP 2.0? In which case I think it would work, but don't know for sure.  I may play with this later, I do lots of mobile web myself and want to know now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use unique URI REST-style requests for Your data, together with cache headers, so Your browser could use it's native page caching.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript only you can go for cookies but they will be [limited in size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543851/chrome-cookie-size-limit) or you can go the new shiny HTML5 [Local Storag](http://html5tutorial.net/tutorials/working-with-html5-localstorage.html)e if you only need to cater modern browsers.

EDIT: You have to open your HTML files through server if you use these, not directly by double clicking!